# C# Process with Python command (+path arguments)

Tags: c#, python, .net, process

I tried to pass a string representation of a python list that stores multiple paths to a Process in C# (later on, I would like to `ast.literal_eval()` the first argument):

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell", command);
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
```

When using `System.Console.Out.WriteLine(command)` I get the following result:

```
python  D:\'Box Sync'\Python\PdfMerge\PdfMerge.py -f "['C:\\Users\foo\Desktop\foo_bar.pdf', 'C:\\Users\foo\Desktop\bar_foo.pdf']" -mt "i" -op "C:\Users\foo\Desktop" -on "output"
```

I can copy that line into my PowerShell command line and when executed it works like a charm. However, trying to execute the script results in an error:

```
PdfMerge.py: error: unrecognized arguments: C:\\Users\foo\Desktop\bar_foo.pdf ]
```

I know that the string

```
"['C:\\\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\foo_bar.pdf', 'C:\\\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\bar_foo.pdf']"
```

works fine with the `ast.literal_eval()` so I want exactly that to be passed as an argument. I also tried to use verbatim string literals but I couldn't get any to work...

Am I missing something obvious?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wouldn't pass a python list of strings as command line arguments of a python program. check for the doc of pdfmerge.

Comment: You are passing "C:\\\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\foo_bar.pdf" which is properly being interpreted as @"C:\\Users\foo\Desktop\foo_bar.pdf".  But, that's not a valid Windows path.  I'm assuming you mean @"C:\Users\foo\Desktop\foo_bar.pdf"  or "C:\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\foo_bar.pdf"

Comment: @Flydog57 But I don't think that that can't be the reason for the error. The string just happened to work with the ast.literal_eval() so it shouldn't have raised an argument err. Using @"['C:\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\foo_bar.pdf', 'C:\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\bar_foo.pdf']" works fine, but "['C:\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\foo_bar.pdf', 'C:\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\bar_foo.pdf']" doesn't (unicodeescape error). I went on to pass @"['C:\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\foo_bar.pdf', 'C:\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\bar_foo.pdf']" but the issue remains...